# Ajax is not working properly in wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm Developing a plugin in which i'm using ajax for deleting and updating information about the uploaded file..

Following is the code:

```
//Creating AJAX for saving value in databsae
add_action('wp_ajax_input_value', 'input_value');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_input_value', 'input_value');

add_action('wp_ajax_update_value', 'update_value');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_update_value', 'update_value');

add_action('wp_ajax_delete_value', 'delete_value');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_delete_value', 'delete_value');

add_action('admin_head', 'input_ajax');
function input_ajax()
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery("#submit").click(function () {
                var input_method = jQuery('#image_url').val();

                var data = {
                    action: 'input_value',
                    input_method: input_method
                };

                jQuery.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', data, function (result) {
//                    alert(result);
                });
            });

            jQuery(".update").click(function () {
                var row = jQuery(this).parents('#list_item');
                var update_id = jQuery(this).data('id-update');
                var update_link = row.find('.img_link').val();
                var update_desc = row.find('.img_description').val();
                var update_title = row.find('.img_title').val();

                var data = {
                    action: 'update_value',
                   id: update_id,
                   update_link: update_link,
                   update_desc: update_desc,
                   update_title: update_title
                };

                jQuery.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', data, function (result) {
//                    alert(result);
                });
            });

            jQuery(".delete").click(function () {
                var delete_id = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');

                var data = {
                    action: 'delete_value',
                    id: delete_id
                };

                jQuery.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', data, function (result) {
//                    alert(result);
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

//Save values in database in "wp_images" table
function input_value()
{
    $name = $_POST['input_method'];

    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert(
        'wp_images',
        array(
            'img_path' => $name
        )
    );
    die();
    return true;
}

//Updating values in database in "wp_images" table
function update_value()
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $link = $_POST['update_link'];
    $desc = $_POST['update_desc'];
    $title = $_POST['update_title'];

    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->update(
        'wp_images',
        array(
            'img_title' => $title,
            'img_description' => $desc,
            'img_link' => $link
        ),
        array('img_id' => $id)
    );
    die();
    return true;
}

//Deleting values in database in "wp_images" table
function delete_value()
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->delete(
        'wp_images',
        array('img_id' => $id)
    );
    die();
    return true;
}
```

it deletes and update properly but not instantly. Means if i delete any row it remains there but when i refresh page then it is removed. I don't know where i have done mistake.

Comment: put location.reload();  where your alert(result); code is

Answer (score 0):

So far your code looks good, but you are not refreshing or cleaning the part of the HTML with the new response.

Your code is going through the post but is not showing any new data in your actual DOM, because you didn't code that new response.